# How to test the active window against a list of windows in an array?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a simple program to solve the inconsistent behaviours I am getting with `Ctrl+C`. In some programs, such as VSCode, `Ctrl+C` copies text to clipboard, even if there is not a active selection.

VSCode offers a means to disable this, but some of my editors do not, such as Windows Terminal

The goal I have in mind is, if one of these "Advanced Editors" is active then send, `Ctrl+X`. Otherwise send `Ctrl+C`. I am stuck on testing the active program against a list of programs I have in mind

```
~space::
AdvancedEditors := ["ahk_exe WindowsTerminal.exe", "ahk_exe Code.exe"]
; BasicEditors  : = ["ahk_exe Notepad.exe"]  

ThisKey := (If WinActive(AdvancedEditors)) ? "x": "c"
SendInput, ^{%Thiskey%}
```

I tried experimenting with the `GroupAdd` command but I could not figure out it. More importantly, I am really keen on learning how I can do this with an array, in the above format. Is that possible?

Thanks allot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GroupAdd](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GroupAdd.htm) is simpler and the program does not need to loop through the array each time ^c is sent.

```
; auto-execute section:

#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

GroupAdd, AdvancedEditors, ahk_exe WindowsTerminal.exe
GroupAdd, AdvancedEditors, ahk_exe Code.exe

; ...

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===


#IfWinActive ahk_group AdvancedEditors

    ^c::^x
    
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: very elegant solution I have to say, good job.

Comment: @devMark, I concur! Thanks allot for this